# Android - How to redirect my app to default messaging application?

Tags: android

In my Android application, I am using SMS validation, When the app shows one popup box with text "Kindly check the message for activation link" and "Messaging" button; When I click the "Messaging" button, It should redirect from my app to device's default messaging application.

How can I redirect my app to default messaging application?

Is it possible in Android?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To launch the sms activity all you need is :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
```

You can add extras to populate your own message and such as

```
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "xyz");
```

then just startActivity with the intent.

```
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("tel:100861");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsUri);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "shenrenkui");
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
send.js.encrypt(SMS_BODY("phone number"));
.request.sms.body("HELLO THIS IS SMS MESAGE");
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**